# Rails STI and the "type" field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, single-table-inheritance

I've followed a few sources to figure out how to implement Single Table Inheritance in Ruby On Rails. The specific example I used just involved 2 types of users: `RegularUser` and `Admin` inheriting from a `User` model that has a few fields like `username`.
One of the fields in the `User` model is the type of the User which is just a String field. My question is: How can Rails connect the dots on which subclass to use when I simply specify it in a String field named "type" which could potentially just be a String field unrelated to the sub-classes? If the `type` field does what I think it does, does that mean it is a keyword reserved solely for STI in RoR?
Any pointers would be much appreciated.
Here is my User migration file (nothing very special about it):

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails has a method to [infer the corresponding class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb#L184) according to the type name

So if in your DB you have a record

```
User, id: 5, type: 'user_admin'
```

and you do `User.find(5)`

Rails will look at the type value 'user_admin' and constantize the right instance for you by basically doing `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.constantize("user_admin")`
Which is a fancy name for saying give me the ruby class that corresponds to this string.

In Rails you shouldn't use "type" as a column name for anything other than to facilitate STI so its kind of a reserved word indeed and you will crash your code if your db holds anything that isn't AR class names in there. If you want to use the name "type" for a column you will need to change the inheritance_column  as explained [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-inheritance_column)

Comment: I like this post about STI https://mattwal.medium.com/sti-polymorphism-and-abstract-classes-rails-a7f588668cbb#:~:text=STI%20is%20one%20of%20Rails'%20provisions%20for%20such%20situations.&text=In%20this%20case%2C%20the%20electorate,to%20which%20a%20record%20belongs.

Answer (score 1):

I think the thing to answer about your question is this.

When a table has a column named `type`, active record will enable STI whether that was your intension or not.  So that is how the dots get connected.  Having a table with a column named `type` can break things if STI was not intended.

You do not have to fill in the value of the `type` field when doing a `create`, active record will populate it with the name of the class.  Doing a `find` from the base (or any inherited classes) will return an instance of the class specified in the `type` column.

All this is enabled from just the mere presence of a column named `type`.